# LAZY Loading : jQuery

Tags: jquery, lazy-loading

Can we lazy load the content manually using jQuery code. I do not want the code just your inputs on what can be the possible implementation.

As of thinking right now, Following is one example.

1. There is table of catalogue which get's populated on click when user
   enter search criterion.
2. AJAX call is triggered with search criterion
3. Ajax return 2000 objects and my catalogue shows 10 items per page.
4. Is it possible to show 10 items as soon as we receive from AJAX **(is this intervention possible ?)** and paint the UI on screen while we are receiving rest of the
   data from ajax call.

Just some heads up would be great....

Comment: no , but you can fetch only 10 records. And fetch next 10 when user clicks next buttor or try to go to next page.

Comment: so correct me if I am wrong, on google image search, on scroll we see new images loading, the same concept is used?

Comment: my understanding is that google makes ajax call when we scroll to fetch next set of items. Its not fetching all the items in single ajax call,  as it will overhead for server also if they fetch all images and user don't scroll later. And as far as i know its not possible to read data from ajax call till it completes

Comment: Above comments are as per my understanding , however i don't have any reference to confirm that it cannot be done , hence posted as commnet wait for sometime, some one will reply. Till that time you can try approach suggested by me.

Comment: Check this also seems duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2517408/how-can-i-implement-lazy-loading-on-a-page-with-500-images?rq=1

Comment: If its only image and small size you can look into CSS Sprite also

Comment: no it's not about images it's about content. I know about sprites and use them but ques is different.

Comment: If its content you take approach shared by me, fetch no. of records you want to show in first go in one call. If you scrolls or goes to next pagge (as per your implementation  , i prefer pagination with next button and page no), fetch next set of data.